# Is there an alternative to using generic foreign keys to handle similar model trees?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, generic-foreign-key

My scenario: I'm trying to build a database to track production schedules for different types of shows. I've mapped that out with the following model structure.

```
class Studio(models.Model):
   ...

class Series(models.Model):
   studio = models.ForeignKey(Studio)
   ...

class Season(models.Model):
   series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
   ...

class Episode(models.Model):
   season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
   ...

class Production(models.Model):
   episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode)
```

But I'm now interested in tracking production of movies as well. This presents a challenge though, because movies don't have the same tree structure as TV. Something like this would be more fitting:

```
class Studio(models.Model):
   ...

class Movie(models.Model):
   studio = models.ForeignKey(Studio)
   ...

class Production(models.Model):
   movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
```

The problem here is that `Production` and `Studio` are exactly the same for both movies and TV (at least in this scenario), so I'm hesitant to have totally separate trees, because this would necessitate duplicating `Production`. One for TV and one for Movies, when the only difference is the foreign key.

Does it make sense to use a `GenericForeignKey` here? Where a production can either point at an `Episode` or `Movie`? I'm hesitant to do so because it sounds like the consensus is to avoid generic foreign keys, but I'm not sure how else to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue a while back, and I came to the conclusion that it would be more efficient (and less trouble later on) with 2 foreign keys, and 2 boolean variables informing the type in these tables.

Also from your code I see no reason to duplicate the Studio model as it is identical, and contains no unique foreign key field. Production model however can be written like this

```
class Production(models.Model):
  movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, null=True)
  episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode, null=True)
  is_movie = models.BooleanField(null=False)
  is_episode = models.BooleanField(null=False)
```

What you choose to identify the foreignkey field up to you but boolean is known for its small size in the database.

Comment: This was essentially the solution I was about to post, although I wonder if you need the boolean values. A simple filter on "movie is not null" would provide the same output.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going to do this but with a `type` field.

Comment: Do you have any benchmark or related data on this? > I came to the conclusion that it would be more efficient